# sum of partial sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ , $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be two bounded sequences. Let $L_a$ , $L_b$ , $L_{a+b}$ be the sets of partial limits of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ , $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(a_n+b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ correspondingly.

Show that $L_{a+b} \subseteq L_a+L_b$.

I started by taking an arbitrary subsequence $(c_n) = (a_n^c+b_n^c)$, and said that if $(a_n^c)$ and $(b_n^c)$ converge, then limit arithmatic applies such that $l_c = l_{a^c}+l_{a^c}$ and thus $l_c \in L_a + L_b$.

I'm now stuck with showing that even if each of these subsequences doesn't have a limit, $l_c\in L_a + L_b$ still holds. I kind of understand it, e.g. with one of the seq's being 1,-1,1,-1,... and the other one the opposite, so their sum is zero for all n and so is the limit. And indeed as there exist subsequences of these alternating sequences with limits 1,-1 with sum 0, the claim holds.

But I can't seem to generalize it. Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $\langle a_{n_k}+b_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $\ell\in L_{a+b}$. The sequence $\langle a_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is bounded, so it has a subsequence $\langle a_{n_{k_i}}:i\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converging to some $\ell_a\in L_a$. The sequence $\langle b_{n_{k_i}}:i\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is bounded, so it has a subsequence converging to some $\ell_b\in L_b$. Now use the fact that every subsequence of $\langle a_{n_k}+b_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $\ell$.

Comment: Ok, got it! Thanks!

Comment: @Yoni: You're welcome!